# HTML/Javascript text Slideshow with unlimited number of components inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make a text Slideshow for my website. I used the following codes and can make a Slideshow with 3 sets of texts inside it.

The problem is: To display 3 sets of text, I need three sets of `<div class="mySlides">` in my html file.
If I have a list of texts with 100 of words inside it (like [cat, dog, chair, tree,...etc.]), how can I change my codes to manage this without writing 100 sets of `<div class="mySlides">`.

Thanks

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    
    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
    
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    
    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    
    }
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
      position: relative;
      background: #f1f1f1f1;
    }
    
    /* Slides */
    .mySlides {
      display: none;
      padding: 200px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: -30px;
      padding: 16px;
      color: #888;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }
    
    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      color: white;
    }
    
    /* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
    .dot-container {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #ddd;
    }
    
    /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
    .dot {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }
    
    /* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
    .active, .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }
    
    /* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
    q {font-style: italic;}
    
    /* Add a blue color to the words */
    .myText {color: cornflowerblue;}
```

```html
    <div class="slideshow-container">
    
      <!-- Full-width slides/quotes -->
      <div class="mySlides">
        <p class="myText">Cat</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides">
        <p class="myText">Dog</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="mySlides">
        <p class="myText">Chair</p>
      </div>
    
      <!-- Next/prev buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: So loop over your array and create the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer creates an array of words.

Then loops through it and generates the DIV, the P and appends that to the slideshow-container.

```js
words = ["cat","dog","mouse","snake","tree"];

container = document.querySelector(".slideshow-container");

words.forEach(function(word){
  div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("mySlides");
  p = document.createElement("p");
  p.classList.add("myText");
  p.innerHTML = word;
  div.appendChild(p)
  container.appendChild(div)
});

var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    
    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
    
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    
    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    
    }
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */
    .slideshow-container {
      position: relative;
      background: #f1f1f1f1;
    }
    
    /* Slides */
    .mySlides {
      display: none;
      padding: 200px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Next & previous buttons */
    .prev, .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: -30px;
      padding: 16px;
      color: #888;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }
    
    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      color: white;
    }
    
    /* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
    .dot-container {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #ddd;
    }
    
    /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
    .dot {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbb;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }
    
    /* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
    .active, .dot:hover {
      background-color: #717171;
    }
    
    /* Add an italic font style to all quotes */
    q {font-style: italic;}
    
    /* Add a blue color to the words */
    .myText {color: cornflowerblue;}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
    
      <!-- Next/prev buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I need!